# In movie Tumbbad why does Sadashiv open his eye after falling

Tags: plot-explanation, tumbbad

[image]

When Sadashiv falls he briefly opens his eyes as if he was doing a prank. Even the music elevates a little when he does so. At first I thought this scene has some supernatural involved. But then ends up dying soon afterwards and this is unexplained.

Comment: I don't know the movie, so this is all I have to go on. With the added gif… *"as if he was doing a prank"* I'm not seeing that at all. I see "wow, that was bad & I'm not sure I can get up…"

Comment: @Tetsujin: I have seen the movie and I agree with you on that one. It's just a last glimmer before his death.

Comment: @Rahul maybe it is the acting which made me think that way then. I don't know it looked like he is trying hard to close his eyes and sleep

Comment: @binga58: Yes. Child actors often don't give perfect shots. Besides this movie took a very long time to shoot and complete hence the inconsistency. Check other answers for better understanding of the story.